# What does this naming convention for headers refer to?

Tags: c++

I was studying Include guards in C++ and came across this naming convention from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard):

```
CREATORSNAME_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS
```

I get now that it is a timestamp but then say

`#ifndef CREATORSNAME_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS`

`#define CREATORSNAME_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS`

`#endif`

then how does the compiler know that it is HeaderName.h ?

Comment: I've seen this in Boost.Proto.

Comment: Doesn't that whole wikipedia page explain exactly what include guards are and how you use them?

Comment: @Rapptz I've seen this everywhere in the standard library.

Comment: @ShuklaSannidhya Maybe in your implementation, but not on mine.

Comment: @Mat Well obviously not! (especially the part with the CREATORSNAME_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS) That's why I asked here!

Comment: It doesn't know that it's HeaderName.h, it doesn't care what file the content is coming from, it is just looking at the content.  Even if the convention of FILENAME_H for include gaurd is followed, the name of the file and the include gaurd tag are still completely separate in the eyes of the compiler.

Comment: @ChrisCM Sorry! Will keep that in mind next time I post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a convenient way to store the documentation about the person who wrote the module and when, that guarantees uniquness of the guard(through the date), and provides additional information for others referencing the module.  Particularly if they believe there to be a problem with it's corresponding implementation, so they have someone to write to.  Otherwise, a creator of a module can forget to add in documentation as to who they are.

```
#ifndef CHRIS_20140807_011555 
#define CHRIS_20140807_011555

struct foo {
    int member;
};

#endif /* CHRIS_20140807_011555 */
```

Alternatively, you could do this, but it doesn't provide additional information and adding the documentation at the top is easy to forget.(Though to be honest, it should become habbit, and SHOULD NOT BE FORGOTTEN).  But, this is still likely the motivation for such practices, despite the option below being much more widely used.

```
/*
* AUTHOR: Chris
* DATE: July 7, 2013
*
* These comments are easy to forget
*/
#ifndef FILENAME_H
#define FILENAME_H

struct foo {
    int member;
};

#endif /* FILENAME_H */
```

This:

```
#ifndef AAAA 
#define AAAA

struct foo {
    int member;
};

#endif
```

and

```
#pragma once

struct foo {
    int member;
};
```

All of these code snippets accomplish the exact same thing.

Comment: thanks , but is there some mechanism that the compiler knows from the timestamp that it is indeed filename.h?

Comment: No, this is just an idiomatic convention, having the tag and the filename be the same.

Comment: but then are you saying that the tag and filename here , viz. CHRIS_19870909_234545 is synonymous to header.h?

Comment: No, I'm saying the two are following different idioms for tagging the include gaurds.  They are completely separate collections of characters defined by the coder.  They need to be unique within a project to function properly.  They could just as easily be unique random collections of letters, and do the exact same thing functionally.  You're really making this much more complex than it is.

Answer (score 2):

For a file called MyFile.h made by John Doe on 2013-01-01 at 12:00 PM, you would use:

```
#ifndef JOHNDOE_20130101_120000
#define JOHNDOE_20130101_120000

// File contents

#endif
```

Why you *wouldn't* want to place the file's name in the include guard is beyond me.

Comment: Agreed on that second point.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is a guarantee of the file's uniqueness in the project.

Comment: @Michael Thanks but then how does the compiler know whether its MyTest.h or SomeOtherHeader.h , since name has not been included here ?

Comment: @Aditya, the compiler doesn't care - as long as these names stay unique, the methodology would work. The hope with this bizarre naming scheme is that you won't create two header files in the same second. I would most definitely include the file name or some variant of it in the macro name if I was to use a variant of this scheme.